# How much information should I jam into a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, style

Are there any guidelines for the amount of information which should be present in a sentence?
Consider the following sentences:

> In this section we describe the algorithm for data extraction from a webpage using a wrapper, which has been created by the user through the GUI explained in the previous sections.
>
> In this section we describe the algorithm for data extraction  <s>from a webpage</s>  using a wrapper,  <s>which has been</s>  created by the user through the GUI explained in the previous sections.
>
> In this section we describe the algorithm for data extraction  <s>from a webpage</s>  using a wrapper,  <s>which has been</s>  created by the user through the GUI  <s>explained in the previous sections.</s>

I know that I can sometimes rely on the context to avoid repeating information.

Which of the sentences above do you recommend?

Comment: They all work! This is a problem of context! How can I possibly know what information you should include when I don't know what comes before or after? Really, only you can answer. Just ask yourself: Is it obvious that it's data extraction **from a webpage**? Do I need to say the GUI is the one explained **in previous sections**? I can only tell you that you can omit your relative pronoun for brevity.

Comment: In general I recommend you **do more reading** of material written by native English speakers so you will have a better idea of how much information usually goes in a sentence in English.

Answer (score 2):

It is never a bad idea to express the core idea clearly and succinctly.

**In this section we describe an algorithm for extracting data from a webpage.**

When it follows a series of nouns, "which" can often cause the reader to stumble, and it does no harm to repeat a noun.

**The algorithm utilizes the wrapper created in the previous section.**